# How can I get a list of Spring Initialization Errors?

Tags: spring

Is it possible to get somewhere a list of Spring Initialization errors?

I looked at `WebApplicationContext` and `ApplicationContext` classes but there is nothing there.

If I do a:

```
WebApplicationContext wac =
     WebApplicationContextUtils.findWebApplicationContext(
         req.getServletContext()
     );
```

I know that Spring failed at initialization when `wac == null`. But, I would love to get a list of all initialization errors that prevented application context to start normally.

Comment: If the spring context couldn't be initialised. On what bean or spring-aware listener can it tell you what failed other than the logs it printed while wiring all the initial beans?